# How to add/update comments to Informatica mapping directly using repository manager?

Tags: repository, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to add/update comments to Informatica mappings using repository manager (may be using pmrep command not sure), so please suggest how I can achieve this with out doing check out of mapping.
I need to add/update comments directly in Production without check out of object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not doable using repo manager.
You can update column  MAPPING_DESCRIPTION in opb mapping table

Comment: I am thinking to do like below, 1. Download mapping xml file using pmrep 2. Replace Mapping_Description =“” with required comments using sed/awk 3. Import xml file again to repo using pmrep. Can you please help here

Comment: totally upto you and depends on your access on informatica. in your case, you have to change each XML manually.

Comment: I am finding to do it automatically like below 1. list all mappings (using pmrep we can get all list of mappings) in one file and add comments to that file manually with ',' separator. So the file will have "Mapping_Name,Mapping_Comments". 2. Then in shell script get the mapping name from file and search for xml present in the folder, if exists then take mapping_comments from file and search for Mapping Description key word in the xml then replace it New comments. 3. After doing changes import the xml back. Can you please help me to get this process achieve.